# String array length printed instead of the Number of Array Items in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, size

I tried this declaration of array and check the size:

```
string path1[1] = {"D:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop\\testing\\inputs\\xml_source_example.xml"};
cout << path1->length();
```

and checked the size:

> > 62

I wanted the output to be 1, so I tried with **->size()** and I still got 62.
I know that the first item in the array has length of 62, but **I want the number of items in the array.**

How can I get how many items there are in the array?

Comment: `path1` when used in this context becomes a pointer to the first element of the array. So it's equivalent to `(*path1).length()` or the `length()` of the first element of the array.

Comment: If path1 is an array and the compiler knows its size you can use `sizeof path1 / sizeof *path1`. However once you pass this array to another function it degrades to a pointer and you can't use that trick anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, leveraging `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
std::end(path1) - std::begin(path1);
```

Alternatively, you can role out your own array size function:

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T(&)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a[42];
  std::cout << size(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: it wroks but is there any explanations for this? when I try end and start it gives me addresses and end-start = good

Comment: @user2410243 The size of an automatic or static storage array is know at compile time. Using templates, `std::begin` and particularly `std::end` use the size information to find the "one past the end" iterator, which for an array is a pointer one past the last element. Subtracting the begin pointer from the end one gives you the number of elements. I added a function that does it all in one, without need for a subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

For any **statically allocated** `array` in C/C++, use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` in order to get the number of entries.

**Note #1:**

The calculation will be made during compilation (and not during runtime).

**Note #2:**

```
int array[10]; // Static allocation
int array[] = new int[10]; // Dynamic allocation
```

**Note #3:**

You can apply this method **only** in the scope of declaration.

For example, if `array` is declared inside a function, then you can apply this method only in the scope of that function. You cannot apply this method inside any other function which receives `array` as an argument, because it is regarded as a pointer within that function.

If the array is declared globally in a source file, then you can apply this method in all functions within that file.

Comment: While being true, this is valid only if you have the array as a reference, not if it was passed as a pointer to a function.

Comment: Added "statically allocated"

Comment: Yeah, you beat me, I posted my comment 0.5 second after your edit ;). I won't remove it for future readers to understand.

Comment: Agreed; note is important.

Answer (score 1):

In c++,arrays aren't managed for you, and will always be the length set at declaration. There are many types of containers which are managed in the [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). I wouldn't hesitate to try out Vectors, if I had to make a reccomendation but have a look see if any of the others fit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. 2 have already been given by juanchopanza and barak manos. Here is the third one

```
#include <type_traits>

int a[12];
std::cout<<std::extent<decltype(a)>::value<<std::endl;
```

But consider using std::array instead of old-C syle array.

Comment: `extent` will return 0 if the bound is unknown. For example: `void func(std::string array[])
{
    std::cout<<std::extent<decltype(array)>::value<<std::endl;
}` will output `0`.

Comment: Sure, but who use that kind of thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
string path1[1] = "D:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop\\testing\\inputs\\
xml_source_example.xml";
cout << sizeof(path1)/sizeof(path1[0]);
```

This will work as per your requirement but when pointer will come it will fail. But as per your requirement, this will suffice.